# Find cube roots of $-1$

Tags: complex-analysis

If $-1$ and $\lambda$ are two cube roots of $-1$ find in terms of $\lambda$ the third cube root of $-1$.

Am I right in saying that it is just $1-\lambda$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are right. We are solving $z^3+1=0$. The sum of the roots is the coefficient of $z^2$, so it is $0$. Thus if $r$ is the third root, we have $r-1+\lambda=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: the sum of roots of a polynomial function $f(X)=\sum_{i=0}^n a_i X^i$ is equal to $-\dfrac{a_{n-1}}{a_n}$